# HTTP/2 Server pushed but it's reloaded the pushed file on Apache2.4

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http2

I just setup a Apache 2.4 server and using http/2.
I configured Server push in the server :

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
                    <Location /index.html>
              Header add Link "</img/2.jpg>; rel=preload"
             </Location>
```

But the server pushed it but it still load this image,
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV2y9.png)

Hope someone could help me :). many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason make it not work, when we use server push something like css, image, js...

We need identified the file we push.

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
                <Location /index.html>
          Header add Link "</img/2.jpg>; rel=preload; as=image"
         </Location>
```